# Pivot and grouping SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server

I have a table like this

```
Employee    Response Code
-------------------------
Emp A       vml
Emp B       wrn
Emp C       ptb
Emp A       wrn
Emp B       ulm
Emp A       vml
Emp B       ulm
Emp C       vml
```

I need to create a report like this from the above table

```
       vml  wrn ptb ulm
------------------------
Emp A   2   1   0   0
Emp B   0   1   0   2
Emp C   1   0   1   0
Totals  3   2   1   2
```

The report table calculates the count of each code for each employee and total calculates the sum of each column at the end

How can I do this? Could anyone please help me? Thank you very much for your time and help

Comment: did you try anything at all?

Comment: I tried grouping . but Did not get the required result. I have actually 100+ response code and 50+ employee in my actual table. I do not know how to pivot and grouping in sql server

Comment: @Please - please update your question with the query you've attempted.

Comment: here is your link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24470/sql-server-examples-of-pivoting-string-data?rq=1  I would note mister blame/shame that this was a simple search on sql server and pivot

Comment: @Hogan I have an actual table with 50 fields and I need actually 2 column from that table. That is the 2 required column I mentioned in the question .

Comment: @Please are values in Response Code column static (predefined) or they can be dynamic, i.e. new possible response codes added over time?

Comment: @andrews Thank you for helping. There is a possibility of adding more response code in future. If I use Case when , I will have to write 100+ case when for each response code. I need it to be dynamic

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server dynamic PIVOT query?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404348/sql-server-dynamic-pivot-query)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll bite.  Seems like a jump-start is needed.

Below are two options:  The first is Dynamic which will allow future response codes.  The second will illustrate the actual PIVOT syntax

**The Dynamic Option**

```
Declare @SQL varchar(max) 
Select  @SQL = Stuff((Select Distinct ',' + QuoteName([Response Code]) From YourTable Order by 1 For XML Path('')),1,1,'') 
Select  @SQL = 'Select [Lvl],[Employee],' + @SQL + '
                From (
                        Select [Employee],[Response Code],Cnt=1,Lvl=0 from YourTable
                        Union All
                        Select ''Total'',[Response Code],count(*),1 From YourTable Group By [Response Code]
                     ) A
                Pivot (sum(Cnt) For [Response Code] in (' + @SQL + ') ) p'
Exec(@SQL);
```

**The Non-Dynamic Option**

```
Select [Lvl],[Employee],[ptb],[ulm],[vml],[wrn]
 From  (
        Select [Employee],[Response Code],Cnt=1,Lvl=0 from YourTable
        Union All
        Select 'Total',[Response Code],count(*),1 From YourTable Group By [Response Code]
        ) A
 Pivot (sum(Cnt) For [Response Code] in ([ptb],[ulm],[vml],[wrn]) ) p
```

Both would return

```
Employee    ptb     ulm     vml     wrn
Emp A       NULL    NULL    2       1
Emp B       NULL    2       NULL    1
Emp C       1       NULL    1       NULL
Total       1       2       3       2
```

> **EDIT - To Remove NULLs**

Notice the additional Union All

```
Declare @SQL varchar(max) 
Select  @SQL = Stuff((Select Distinct ',' + QuoteName([Response Code]) From YourTable Order by 1 For XML Path('')),1,1,'') 
Select  @SQL = 'Select [Lvl],[Employee],' + @SQL + '
                From (
                        Select [Employee],[Response Code],Cnt=1,Lvl=0 from YourTable
                        Union All
                        Select [Employee],[Response Code],Cnt=0,Lvl=0 from (Select Distinct [Employee] from YourTable) A Join (Select Distinct [Response Code] from YourTable) B on 1=1
                        Union All
                        Select ''Total'',[Response Code],count(*),1 From YourTable Group By [Response Code]
                     ) A
                Pivot (sum(Cnt) For [Response Code] in (' + @SQL + ') ) p'
Exec(@SQL);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help . I will try this solution

Comment: Good answer, the only problem was with 'Select * ...' and following UNION ALL. I have added PK_Employees column as PK to my test table and UNION ALL complained about column number mismatch. There may be also other columns which SELECT * will fetch and they are not included in the UNION ALL call. So we need the exact CREATE TABLE/INSERT scripts from the OP OR you need to convert * to the list of actual columns in the SELECT statement.

Comment: @andrews Took you suggestion and removed the Select *

Comment: @John Cappelletti Thank you very much. Is is working exactly like I wanted

Comment: @Please Happy to help.

Comment: @Please Don't for get to select it as the answer

Comment: @John Cappelletti Thank you. Unfortunately, I do not have enough points in starkoveflow to mark any answer. Once I got 15 point I will mark the answer. Once again thank you very much for your time and help

Comment: @Please No worries.  I forgot they had the initial threshold.  cheers

Comment: @John Cappelletti I tried to replace the null values with empty string. I am not able to get the correct result. I tried to put isnull(count(*),0) and I am getting error message. Could you please help me

Comment: @Please See EDIT in updaed answer

Comment: @John Cappelletti Million times thank you. It works perfect. This script is very new to me and without your help I could never solve the problem. Please forgive me If I am disturbing you. Is there a way I can export this dynamic result to a table or flat file? Because my goal is to export the result set into excel and send it over.

Comment: @Please Once again, happy to help

Answer (score 0):

based on your last comment, you need to use Dynamic Pivot, because by default for PIVOT operator you need to provide a static list of columns to pivot.

See my answer to somewhat similar question:
[How-to-convert-many-to-many-entity-relationship-to-tabular-view-in-sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39934832/how-to-convert-many-to-many-entity-relationship-to-tabular-view-in-sql/39948541#39948541)

Especially pay attention to the dynamic pivot part.

If the mentioned answer is too difficult for you to understand, then search google for SQL Server Dynamic Pivot. Here is a sample result: [Script to create dynamic PIVOT queries in SQL Server](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2783/script-to-create-dynamic-pivot-queries-in-sql-server/)

Hope this helps. If still in trouble, post in comments what you have tried and what didn't work.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. I will try this and let you know. I really appreciate you helping mind. God bless you :)

Comment: No problem, @Please. You'll learn by try-and-fail. Next time you ask something about SQL be sure to include the CREATE TABLE/INSERT INTO scripts, so that users may replicate your data locally, also try to post what you have tried. This comment may be flagged and removed, but I will say anyways: I'm also a Christian and God has changed my stone-like heart not to be a snob or smth. So may God bless you too and help you learn SQL ;)!

Comment: Thank you. I will keep all these things in my mind .